# ¿Como puedo programar un textbox para que al darle doble clic me lo auto complete con informacion de BD?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hace poco me enrolle en un proyecto y tengo una duda, en que si es posible **(y si lo es como?)** poder programar un `textbox` que al escribir una información y al darle doble clic a ese mismo `textbox` me auto complete la información referente a la base de datos de otro `textbox`.

Ejemplo:

Tengo dos `textbox`, uno para **IDAlumno** y otro para el **Nombre**.

En uno coloco el **IDAlumno**, al haber finalizado de escribir ese **ID** y al darle doble clic, me auto complete el `textbox` de **Nombre**, con el **nombre** de la
persona referente a ese **ID**

El codigo esta asi, cree  para el auocompletado

```
Sub autocompletarTextbox(ByVal campoTexto As TextBox)
    Try
        conexion.Open()
        comando = New SqlCommand("SELECT IDAlumno from Alumno", conexion)
        respuesta = comando.ExecuteReader()
        While respuesta.Read
            campoTexto.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(respuesta.Item("IDAlumno"))

        End While
        respuesta.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

y en el load simplemente llame la funcion pasando como parametro mi `textbox`

autocompletarTextbox(NumeroCuenta)

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. En su forma actual, la respuesta a tu pregunta sería un simple _si se puede_. Hay muchos ejemplos en el Internet. Estoy seguro que si googleas términos como _ajax_ y _textbox + ajax_ vas a encontrar suficiente material para encaminarte. Cuando tengas alguna duda puntual o algún error que no logres resolver, StackOverflow es el sitio adecuado para lanzar esa pregunta. Esta, sin embargo, en mi opinión, no es apta para el sitio. Para más información lee también [help/on-topic]

Comment: TODO es posible, y claro, tu petición lo es, lo que harías básicamente es una consulta donde pases como parámetro el ID del alumno, algo como **select Nombre from tuTable where IDAlumno = id ** donde id = al contenedor de tu TextBox (IDAlumno)...Algo muy ciego ya que no se como tengas estructurado tu tabla. Podrías mostrar algún avance que tengas para que en base a ello se te pueda orientar mejor. Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) puede serte de utilidad.

Comment: Hola Celeste, ¿Podrías por favor incluir lo que has intentado hasta ahora para ayudarte mejor?

Comment: eso es lo que e logrado hasta el momento

Comment: Hola Celeste, lo podrías hacer con el método OnChange del textbox que mencionas. ahora para una mejor experiencia de usuario busca como aplicar este mismo método de manera asincrona.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para que te ejecute el evento dobleClick en un textbox debes de dirigirte al apartado de eventos como muestro en la imagen , después le das doble click para que te abra el evento y sucesivamente llamas la función que quieras que se ejecute cuando pase ese evento
Por ejemplo en tu caso quieres que al poner un ID en un textbox te llene con el nombre en el otro.
ok primero debes de ingresar el id y en ese mismo textbox aplicarle el evento dobleclick cosa que cuando tengas el id del alumno al darle doble click coje el id del alumno y lo manda como parametro a una funcion que te retorna el nombre del alumno con tan solo el id y desapues cuando tengas el nombre del alumno.
lo pones en el textbox que tu quieres que aparezca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]